# Adding labels to a dendrogram in ggplot using ggdendro in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, dendrogram, hclust

How can I add labels to a ggdendro plot? I realise from reading ?dendro_data that I am suppose to use the the call 'labels' but can't find an example of actual implementation. Could anybody please demonstrate how to add leaf labels to the example below. Thank you

```
require(ggplot2)

hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
dhc <- as.dendrogram(hc,hang=0.1)
ddata <- dendro_data(dhc, type="rectangle")
ggplot(segment(ddata)) + geom_segment(aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add leaf labels with a call to `geom_text()` using the data frame generated by `label(ddata)`. I also extended the plot range using `scale_y_continuous` so the labels were not cutoff .

```
p <- ggplot(segment(ddata)) + geom_segment(aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend))
p + geom_text(aes(x = x, y = y, label = label, angle = -90, hjust = 0), data= label(ddata)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.3, 0))
```

It may, however, be preferable to use `ggdendrogram()` unless you do not like the way those labels are displayed:

```
ggdendrogram(ddata)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Just one more tiny question....is there any way to adjust the labels so that when hang=0.1 they will be positioned near to wear the branch ends and no all along the bottom? Thanks.

Comment: The answer is yes, but it would require substantial work. Variable hang does not seem to implemented at all in the ``ggdendro`` package so we could not use ``dendro_data`` without heavy modification.

Comment: @orizon I agree. The only thing I manage is to push them a bit away from the endings of the branches with `nudge_x` or `nudge_y` in `geom_text`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to plot hanging dendrograms in ggdendro without a substantial amount of work by applying the following. You just have to construct a dataframe of the labels that also contains the leaf positions. This is done by filtering out the points to only take integers.

```
# tree is a an extracted dendro_data() object.
label_data <- bind_cols(filter(segment(tree), x == xend & x%%1 == 0), label(tree))

ggplot() + 
geom_segment(data=segment(tree), aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend)) +
geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=xend, y=yend, label=label, hjust=0, color = LT), size=2) +
coord_flip() + 
scale_y_reverse(expand=c(0.2, 0)) +
theme_bw() +
theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      axis.line = element_blank(),
      axis.title = element_blank(),
      axis.text = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      legend.position = "None")
```